# Error cache in joomla 1.5?

Tags: joomla1.5

In joomla 1.5 I turn on cache in plugin and config in Global Configuation, then I run website

But when I turn off connect to database is error can't using cache has been created

And alert error `Database Error: Unable to connect to the database:Could not connect to database`

=> How using cache in joomla and not use connect database in 15 minutes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think joomla 1.5 should connect database when using cache